# Docker containerd-shim cost too much memory

Tags: docker

I want to deploy 100 containers to one of my linux pc.

If not use docker, the memory is ok for that 100 services.

But if use docker, I see next:

```
 25504  0.0  0.0  10796  5060 ?        Sl   12:41   0:00 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/779ab7bff4bed93d2912437e58e9b830c2f72ef2d8f3b4a5ba31e6d0db8e72b2 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
```

That means for one container, `containerd-shim` will cost `5M` memory, the worse thing is: for every new container there will be one `containerd-shim` process. This means for 100 containers, there will be additional `5M * 100 = 500M` memory consume.

Is above expected? Any chance for me to try to reduce the `500M`?

Comment: did you already try to limit the container resources ? https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory

Comment: @LinPy I not mean the resource used by docker container itself, I mean next: `dockerd -> containerd -> containerd-shim (runc) -> PID1`. As you know, `dockerd & containerd` just has one instance, but `containerd-shim` will control `runc` to start `container`, every one container will have one `containerd-shim` which could make container survive even dockerd crash. As the parent process of `PID1`, it cost too much memory. I once heard, we can somehow not use `containerd-shim`, just use `containerd` to start `runc`, but not sure, so have this question here.

Comment: @LinPy It's a pity that `medium.com` was blocked in my network environment, would you please give a pleasure to make it as an answer so I can have a learn?

Answer (score 1):

steps to use `runc`

-Extract `json` from `Docker image`:

```
mkdir my_container
cd my_container
mkdir rootfs
docker export $(docker create busybox) | tar -C rootfs -xvf -
docker-runc spec
```

-start the container

```
runc run container-name
```

[Source](https://medium.com/faun/docker-containerd-standalone-runtimes-heres-what-you-should-know-b834ef155426)

**PS** : you may also try to add the run time to `Docker daemon`:

```
docker daemon --add-runtime "oci=/usr/local/sbin/runc"
```

Comment: I upvote this as it could run, but seems turns out there is no solution as even this can not meet my requirement. Because, I found `runc` behavior not as I expected, I suppose `one containerd` handle all `containers`, but in fact it's `multiple runc` handle `multiple containers`. I don't have many `containerd-shim` now, but still have lots `runc` for multiple containers. What's worse, `containerd-shim` consume `5M` while `runc` consume `17M`. And `containerd-shime` is a process to allow `runc` to leave, so I guess `containerd-shime` made more optimization to allow daemonless. Anyway, thanks.